# Thunderbolt 1 array - mac mini

Tags: server, automount, thunderbolt, mac-mini, 22.10

I have an install of Ubuntu server on a mac mini (late 2012) that I'm trying to get a thunderbolt disk array to work on. I'm running Ubuntu server 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-23

Formatted the drives as a single logical drive using the promise utility on a mac running macOS and then formatted the logical drive as ext4 using gparted booted from a USB stick, where it had been recognized, but once I plug the array into the mini running linux all I can do is get the array to show as authorized.

I've used boltctl to authorize and enroll the thunderbolt array, and running boltctl info shows the below but not consistently. It will go back and forth between showing the array as authorized, and disconnected. When it is authorized, I can see it listed as 0-3 in /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/

```
 Promise Technology, Inc. Pegasus R-Series
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          Pegasus R-Series
   ├─ vendor:        Promise Technology, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          70dd0900-0000-0200-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ dbus path:     /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/70dd0900_0000_0200_ffff_ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    Thunderbolt 1
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     xxxxxxxx-0c00-0100-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ parent:     xxxxxxxx-0c00-0100-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ syspath:    /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/domain0/0-0/0-3
   │  ├─ rx speed:   10 Gb/s = 1 lanes * 10 Gb/s
   │  ├─ tx speed:   10 Gb/s = 1 lanes * 10 Gb/s
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Sun 23 Oct 2022 10:12:33 PM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Sun 23 Oct 2022 10:12:33 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        Sun 23 Oct 2022 03:01:43 AM UTC
      ├─ policy:     auto
      └─ key:        no
```

With or without the array showing as authorized, I can't seem to find it listed anywhere. Output from lsblk doesn't show it, neither does sudo fdisk -l so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about trying to mount the thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll keep looking to see what I can find, but right now it is not looking to promising to be used with Linux:  https://forum.promise.com/thread/manage-pegasus-r4-on-linux/

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I think as long as I don't actually need to config/manage the array from within ubuntu server the support from Promise won't matter.


For what it's worth I had gotten the array to be recognized under a different version of linux a while back (ubuntu desktop maybe?), but I was hoping to run server this time around so as not to have all the overhead of a desktop environment, etc.